# How long does compiling minix take?

Tags: unix, compilation, operating-system, cross-compiling, minix

I downloaded the Minix source code through git:

```
 git clone git://git.minix3.org/minix minixsrc
```

Then I followed the instructions on [Crosscompiling MINIX with build.sh](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:crosscompiling)
 and ran the command

```
sh build.sh -mi386 -O ../build tools
```

Now I have been waiting for about an hour for it to compile and it is continuously showing messages on my terminal like this:

```
#   compile  libclangSema/SemaExprMember.lo
c++ -O -O2 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions  -I. -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/tools/llvm-lib/libclangSema/../../llvm/../../external/bsd/llvm/lib/../dist/clang/include -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/tools/llvm-lib/libclangSema/../../llvm/../../external/bsd/llvm/lib/../dist/lld/include -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/tools/llvm-lib/libclangSema/../../llvm/../../external/bsd/llvm/lib/../dist/llvm/include -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/tools/llvm-lib/libclangSema/../../llvm/../../external/bsd/llvm/lib/../dist/mclinker/include -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/tools/llvm-lib/libclangSema/../../llvm/../../external/bsd/llvm/lib/../dist/lldb/include -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DCLANG_ENABLE_STATIC_ANALYZER -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/../build/tools/llvm-include -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/../build/tools/llvm/config/include -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/../build/tools/llvm/config/tools/clang/include -I/home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/tools/llvm-lib/libclangSema/../../llvm/../../external/bsd/llvm/lib/../config/mclinker -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -c -o SemaExprMember.lo.o    /home/keeyan/git/minixsrc/tools/llvm-lib/libclangSema/../../llvm/../../external/bsd/llvm/lib/../dist/clang/lib/Sema/SemaExprMember.cpp
mv SemaExprMember.lo.o SemaExprMember.lo
```

My question is, how long should this process take? Is something wrong?

#### System Specs:

OS: Linux Mint 18 64bit
CPU: Intel Core i7-5500U CPU @ 2.4GHz x 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should take this long to do the job. It took me about 2 hours for the `sh build.sh -mi386 -O ../build tools c` to finish and it completed successfully and I got the build tools. After that process I ran the `sh build.sh -mi386 -O ../build -U distribution` command and that also took a number of hours. I ended up with the built distribution of MINIX which is what was expected of the process. It seems after that there is no way to turn this into an ISO though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the build script unsets MAKEFLAGS but you can do:

```
MAKEFLAGS=-j\ $(nproc) sh build.sh -mi386 -O ../build tools
```

nproc returns the number of cores in your CPU so it uses all cores and is faster.